# Getting error with taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"

Tags: java, spring, maven, tiles, apache-tiles

I added tiles dependency in pom.xml.

I get error on my jsp page when I am adding this line <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.nated.app.migration</groupId>
<artifactId>nated</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>nated Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <tiles.version>2.2</tiles.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Spring dependency starts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Spring dependency Ends -->
    <!-- MySQL Driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>nated</finalName>
    <!-- Set JDK Compiler Level -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now when ever i am running mvn eclipse:eclipse,its only downloading pom file not jar file Please see the Image below image-1 and image-2.That's why i am getting error see img-3
[image: Image-1]

[image: image-2]

[image: img-3]

Answer (score 0):

Looking on maven central (http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.apache.tiles%22%20AND%20a%3A%22tiles-api%22) I can't find tiles-api in version `2.2`.

Actually this is true of all the tiles dependencies.

Try changing to use 2.2.0 (or 2.2.1 or 2.2.2) instead:

```xml
<properties>
    ...
    <tiles.version>2.2.0</tiles.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: tried with 2.2.0 same problem only downloading pom not jar.please suggest any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your entire JSP code but in addition to above answers, also make sure that all the pages which you have referenced in this jsp have

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
```

at top of the page or it will fail to load.

Comment: I have this problem, and I add taglib and I get JBWEB004113: The absolute uri: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application